# How to scan for elements in the array that have the longest shared prefix with the query term?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, geohashing

i have an array in python that looks like this `['u1jr00', 'u1jr01', 'u1jr02', 'u1jr03', 'u1jr04', 'u1jr05', 'u1jr06','u1jrbjk']`. i am trying to find the element in this array that closely matches with this string in the query `u1jrbjvnrqz7`. How can i scan through the whole array and find the elements with the most common prefix matchin with the query string ? are there any built-in functions in python for common prefix matching?

Comment: Are you looking for the element that has the longest shared prefix with the query term?

Comment: This is too localized. What does all of this code have to do with the question in the title?

Comment: @JoeHalliwell ...@timgeb yes that's exactly what i am looking for. how can i get that?

Comment: @JoeHalliwell..@timgeb could you please take back the downvotes on my question as this question has been answered properly and i have edited the question accordingly? i don't want to have my account blocked

Comment: I think your question is okay; I haven't downvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
items = ["abc", "abcd", "abcde", "zasd"]
query = "abcd"
best_match = max((os.path.commonprefix([item, query]), item) for item in items)[1]
```

This treats all items with the same length of common prefix equally. If you want to prefer smaller ones:

```
best_match = max((os.path.commonprefix([item, query]), -len(item), item) for item in items)[2]
```